# Google maps toggle kml and json layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, kml

Im working with the Google maps API.

I am loading a KML file and a JSON file with jQuery.

The KML file is bike routes in Toronto and the JSON files shows markers for where the Bike Share stations are in Toronto.

When both are loaded, the bike routes don't show up... I think this is because the two files are too big (but but by themselves they load up fine).

Anyway, I would like to load the page with the JSON file, then have a button that when clicked removes the markers and loads the KML file.  Another button would remove the KML file and load the markers.

I can't find a way to do this.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <script type="text/javascript"           src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDr2ZlJyFHjsjjItTPK7_bvRiw_YBchXW4">
    </script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.richardbeardwood.com/stylesassign3.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">


    function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.663112,-79.403468),
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    mapOptions);



   $.getJSON("http://api.citybik.es/bixi-toronto.json", function(json1) {

     var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


     $.each(json1, function(key, data) {

        var lat = data.lat; 
        var newLat = lat.toString().match(/.{2}/g).join('.');
        var nextLat = newLat.split('.');
        var finLat = nextLat.shift() + '.' + nextLat.join('');

        var lng = data.lng; 
        var newLng = lng.toString().match(/.{3}/g).join('.');
        var nextLng = newLng.split('.');
        var finLng = nextLng.shift() + '.' + nextLng.join('');

        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(finLat, finLng);

  // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
  //var imagebike = 'http://www.richardbeardwood.com/bikes_maps_marker.png';
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
           icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon53.png'
       });  
       var bikeLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
           url: 'http://www.richardbeardwood.com/TorontoCyclingMap.kml.xml'
      });
          bikeLayer.setMap(map);

    // Attaching a click event to the current marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
      var gettime = new Date(data.timestamp);
      var time = gettime.toString();
        infoWindow.setContent('<div id="iw-container"><div class="iw-title">' + data.name + '</div><div class="iw-content"><p><img src="http://www.richardbeardwood.com/Bicyle-Symbolgreen.jpg" height="115" width="114"></p><p> As of ' + time + ' at this location there are:<br><br><strong><span class="large">Available docks: ' + data.free + '<br><br>Available bikes: ' + data.bikes + '</span></strong></div></div>');
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      marker.setMap(map);
    });
  });
}

    </script>
    <script>
function clearMarkers() {
bikeLayer.setMap(null);
}
  </script>
   </head>
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new KmlLayer for _every_ marker?  That only needs to be done once (probably best to do it just after you create the map, before you make the AJAX request)

Comment: Good point. Both layers are showing up now. Thanks